# How to modify a child component's colour attribute from the parent in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-props

I have a child `Card` component:

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="500"
    color=color
    outlined
    dark
  >
    <v-list-item three-line>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <div class="overline mb-4">
          OVERLINE
          {{color}}
        </div>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">
          Headline 5
        </v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle>Greyhound divisely hello coldly fonwderfully</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>

      <v-list-item-avatar
        tile
        size="80"
        color="grey"
      ></v-list-item-avatar>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        outlined
        rounded
        text
      >
        Button
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Card',
    props: {
      color: String
    }
  }
</script>
```

And from the parent component I want to pass in the `color` to the child. A part of the parent component's code is shown below.

```
<template>
  <Card v-bind:color="color"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   data() {
      return {
        color: "#FFC400"
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

As you can see I tried to use a prop to pass the `color` from the parent to the child, however even though I'm able to pass the data to the child, `{{color}}` prints out `#FFC400`  I'm not sure how to assign the color value to the `v-card`'s color attribute. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing missing is to also bind the prop to the `color` attribute of the `<v-card>`, otherwise it's only receiving the string "color", rather than the variable of that name.

You can use `v-bind:color="color"` or the shorthand `:color="color"`

```html
<v-card
  class="mx-auto"
  max-width="500"
  :color="color"
  outlined
  dark
>
```